# Compiler error with extra braces 'auto is not allowed here'

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class myarray : public std::array<T, N>
{
};

int main()
{

   myarray< myarray<unsigned int , 4>, 8> test2d;
   // Why does using an extra pair of braces gives a compile error
   for ((auto &n : test2d)) {
     n.fill(0xdeadbeef); // init a 2D array
   }    
   return 0;
}
```

So, my editor inserted an extra pair of braces - and I was surprised that the code did not compile. Can anyone explain what is going on here.

Answer (score 6):

It's nothing to do with auto - this won't compile either:

```
int main()
{
    int a[5];
    for(( int n : a )) {
    }
}
```

The extra brackets attempt to turn whats inside them into an expression.